# Iterating over two lists and adding to a result list returns an empty list. Why?

Tags: list, f#

The result of running the following code returns an empty list but I am not quite sure why. 
My guess is that iterating on the for loop has an effect I don't understand just yet, I know that if I change the result list to be mutable everything works 
Please note there is no relationship between *fileNames* and *games* (ie there could be any number of games or files they don't need to match one to one)

```
let createList (fileNames: string list) = 
    let games = [ "DMC";"Aztez"]    
    let result = List.empty<(string * string)>                
    for filename in fileNames do
        for game in games do
            let a = [filename, game] 
            result = result @ a
    result
```

In the lines inside the two for loops there is a warning: "This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.   "

The code below has the expected behaviour

```
let createListM (fileNames: string list) = 
    let games = [ "DMC";"Aztez"]    
    let mutable result = List.empty<(string * string)>                
    for filename in fileNames do
        for game in games do
            let a = [filename, game] 
            result <- result @ a
    result
```

but It would be better if I didn't have to use a mutable list.

So to sum up, I would like to know
a) why in the first code sample result is empty. Why the new values are not appended with @ (I tried with :: as well)
b) is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the warning suggests, the line

```
result = result @ a
```

evaluates to a `bool` which indicates whether the lists `result` and `result @ a` are equal. This bool is then discarded. Therefore your for loops just iterate over both collections and calculate a number of bools which are never used.

You can use yield to create a list comprehension instead of using mutable variables:

```
let createListM (fileNames: string list) = 
    let games = [ "DMC";"Aztez"]                
    [for filename in fileNames do
        for game in games do
            yield (filename, game)]
```